# How can I access a page's content inside a frame?

Tags: wpf

I have a frame inside mainwindow, inside it there's a page with panels and various contents.
The mainwindow decides wich page to load, and then must interact with their contents (here is the problem).

I've tried many solution and the best is this, but returns pageLogin as a null object

```
    _mainFrame.Source = new Uri(@"/Pages/Login.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    Page pageLogin = this._mainFrame.Content as Page;
```

where _mainFrame is of course the name of the frame inside t mainwindow, and Login.xaml is the content with the Login_panel Stackpanel inside

Comment: Does Login.Xaml inherit from Page? Or does it inherit from Window or UserControl?

Comment: Also, in your debugger in Visual Studio you should be able to see what  object this._mainFrame.Content actual is.

Comment: The _mainFrame perfectly shows the page, but I need to interact with the contens

Comment: Yes, it inherits from Window.Controls.Page

Comment: With your code, pageLogin will only be null if this._mainFrame.Content is null or not a Page object.

Comment: I'll better show more code
This is the Login.xaml class

`
        namespace Mosaic.Pages
        {
         public partial class Login : Page
         {
          public Login()
          {
           InitializeComponent();
          }
        
         
         }
        }
`

Comment: I am also seriously concerned with what you are trying to do. Have you read about MVVM? You really should never need to have to do what you are trying to do. See this link: http://www.wpfsharp.com/2011/04/05/navigation-and-pages-using-model-view-viewmodel-mvvm/

Comment: Yes, but it's a simple project that I'm using also to better learn basics.
I want to end to mvvm/prism, but all that I've read until now is a little too specific or too theoric for me to grasp at the moment

Answer (score 7):

OK. So first, I think you might be going about this the wrong way to start. Check out this project.
http://www.wpfsharp.com/2011/04/05/navigation-and-pages-using-model-view-viewmodel-mvvm/

Try this example:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        >
    <Grid>
        <Frame Name="MainFrame" Source="/Login.xaml"></Frame>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var a = MainFrame.Content as Page;
            var grid = a.Content as Grid;
            var textBlock = grid.Children[0];
            // bla bla, you logged in
            MainFrame.Source = new Uri("/Home.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            var b = MainFrame.Content as Page; // Still Login.xaml
            MainFrame.ContentRendered +=MainFrame_ContentRendered;
        }

        private void MainFrame_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var b = MainFrame.Content as Page; // Is now Home.xaml
        }
    }
}
```

Login.xaml

```
<Page x:Class="Test.Login"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
    Title="Login">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock>This is a sample login page.</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: I think that's the solution, but Window_Loaded is not being fired... (I'm still a noob in c# :/)

Comment: Did you add Loaded="Window_Loaded" to the MainWindow.xaml in the <Window> tag?

Comment: Thanks I knowed I was missing something important :S

Now it is fired but throw an unmanaged System.NullReferenceException on var grid = a.Content as Grid;

Comment: I've checked and is the a that is null, but the page content is loaded in the frame

Comment: It is because you aren't giving it time to render. See my MainWindow.xaml in my updated answer.

Comment: I'm still a little confused so it's best to follow your advice and return to study some more