# Two windows display and control WPF C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am pretty new in WPF C#. I am held up with the following Issue:

Lets say I have a `MainWindow.xaml`, and have the main program logic in it.

I have a second window, called `Second.xaml`

I am calling `Second.xaml` in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`,
currently I am doing:

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
var wind = new Second();
wind.Show();
```

This successfully opens the second window, where I have a few buttons.
My motive is to trigger events in `MainWindow` using `Second.xaml.cs`

(i.e.)
in  Second.xaml.cs:

```
....
..
MainWindow mainwindowID = new MainWindow();
....
..
.

private void nextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mainwindowID.textBox.Content = "Displaying In Mainwindow";
}
```

When I click the <kbd>Next</kbd> button in `Second.xaml`, I want the text Box inside `Mainwindow` to be updated.

Though the program in running, nothing changes inside `MainWindow`.
Is it possible to control it like that?

I have the `MainWindow` displayed using a projector, and the second window on the monitor. So I trigger events inside the second window and want them to be displayed in the `MainWindow`.

Is there any other solution for this kind?

Update:
If the textbox is inside `SecondPage.xaml` and displayed inside `MainWindow.xaml` using a Frame, how do I call it from `Second.xaml`?

Answer (score 2):

In the first window (MainWindow) you can invoke the second window in this way:

```
var wind = new Second();
wind.FirstWindow = this;
wind.Show();
```

while the second window can look like this:

```
public MainWindow FirstWindow { get; set; }

private void nextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FirstWindow.textBox.Content = "Displaying In Mainwindow";   
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works!
If I have the textbox inside anotherPage.xaml and displayed using a Frame inside MainWindow.xaml, What to do?

Comment: @ViswaSekar I think you should ask another question because it's a different problem. You can also browse these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080482/how-can-i-access-a-pages-content-inside-a-frame or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802911/communicate-between-pages-in-wpf

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `Delegates`. Have a look at the link here;

[Delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx)

This way you can create a method in the first `Window` like so;

```
private void WaitForResponse(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var second = new SecondWindow();
    second.ReturnTextBoxText += LoadTextBoxText;
    SecondWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

Then in your second `Window`;

```
internal Action<string, int> ReturnTextBoxText;

private void nextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ReturnTextBoxText("Displaying In Mainwindow");   
}
```

Finally load that response in your first `Window`;

```
private void LoadSelectedCompany(string text, int passedCompanyID)
{
    contactCompanyTextBox.Text = companyName;
}
```